# What are empty requests in web server log?

Tags: web-browser, nginx

In my nginx access.log I have plenty of request logs like this:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [18/Aug/2014:12:09:33 +0200] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

As you see there is neither browser specification nor any target url.  I am wondering whether they could be part of an attack scheme (what sort of?) and if so how best to counter them?

Comment: You mind if i see your nginx config file also Vhost file

Comment: Check what ends up in the log when you [send (using telnet)](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Check_TCP_Port_80_%28http%29_with_telnet) a request with missing fields, or an emtpy request.

Answer (score 3):

That's the result of somebody sending an empty request to your server.  It's not a useful attack vector by itself (as you can see from the log, your server returned a "400 Bad Request" error message), but it can be used as an "is there a webserver here?" probe.

Personally, I'd ignore it.  There's a lot of automated scanning going on out there, and you could spend untold hours trying to stop things that aren't a threat in the first place.

Comment: If the number of these empty requests is high, increasing, or is coming at the same time from ≠ `@IP`, this might be the sign of the tuning of a DOS.

Comment: @danielAzuelos, an empty request doesn't make a very good DoS.  Returning an error code requires very little processing power and, for a sensibly-configured server, only marginally more bandwidth than the original request.